# sql - check if column begins with a specific regex

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following regex `[0-9]\.`

I can get all of these occurrences from a specific column using:

```
select Col1 from tblTest where Col1 like '%[0-9]\.%'
```

This will return the column will contain the string: "text text text 55. text text text"

My aim is to find the "55." and wrap it with a "- -"

So essentially, after i run a query the string will then become: "text text text -55.- text text text"

How can i find the regex from that column, and replace it with "text text text -" & RegexMatch & "- text text text"?

Comment: What if the text was `blah 55. blah 66. blah`? Also, SQL Server doesn't do Regex, it just has plain old pattern matching.

Comment: You can't, because SQL Server does not have a regex replace function, at least none which is built in.

Comment: `LIKE` supports a form of wildcarding, but it does not support regexes. `[0-9]\.` is not correct because ``\`` is not an escape character (and `.` does not need to be escaped). For sufficiently simple patterns, replacing a found pattern can be done with `PATINDEX` and `STUFF`, but if you can't predict the length of your pattern in advance things get a whole lot more annoying.

Comment: I have to find all the occurrences where it there is a number, followed by a fullstop.. if there was a number by itself then that is valid

Comment: SQL CLR would let you use use a C# regular expression for this.  If you can pull the data into a file, you could use C# to manipulate it, bulk load the primary key and the updated text, and then update the text to the replaced values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use like and replace:

```
declare @searchStr varchar(10) = '55.';
select replace(Col1, @searchStr, '-' + @searchStr + '-') 
from tblTest
where Col1 like ('%' + @searchStr + '%');
```

Keep in mind though, the predicate isn't sargable.